# Change the input value in shiny from server

Tags: r, shiny

I have an action botton with `id=do`, i would want change the value of and input called rhm_clic when the acction boton is clicked. I have this at the moment.

```
 observeEvent(input$do,{
   input$rhm_clic<-NULL
 })
```

Comment: Depending of the type of input, you can use `shiny::updateXXXInput` or `shiny::updateYYYButton` - You'll have to have a session argument in the `server` function. Have a look at `?updateNumericInput`

Comment: I used the update functions but they did not work. Could it be because I create the input with Shiny.onInputChange from JavaScript?

Answer (score 12):

There is an alternative to this which uses JS which I found to be very useful in some cases. This allows you to not have to use the `update***input` functions. Additionally, the input doesn't even need to have been previously defined.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('rhm_clic', function(value) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('rhm_clic', value);
    });
  ")

# additional UI code
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("rhm_clic", 'null')
  })
# Additional server code
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is a good [article by Joe Cheng](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) laying out how to use this framework.

Answer (score 3):

At the end I opted to create a button action from JavaScript and use the Shiny.onInputChange JavaScript function. The following code, in the ui, solved my problem

```
#Create a button with HTML, with a specific id
HTML('<button id="mydiv" type="button" 
class="btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input"> 
Change The Value</button>'), 

#Using the javaScript Shiny.onInputChange function to restore the input value.
tags$script(' document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = function() {
 Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", number); }; ')
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is 2 years old, but I'm putting my own answer down since it seems pretty straightforward.

I just re-created the output object within the observeEvent and pre-selected the value I wanted.

```
actionButton("do","Putlabelhere")

observeEvent(input$do,{
output$doSomethingElse = renderUI(selectInput("doSomethingElse", "This is a selectbox whose value I'm changing", choices = c("choice1","choice2","choice3","newchoice"), selected = "newchoice", multiple = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: You could add the UI code: `uiOutput("doSomethingElse")`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the values of shiny created inputs in this way. For an `input$` variable to be changed it would need to be changed by an actual input process such as `inputText()` or `actionButton()`. Technically theres an additional way but it's an undocumented work around, so pointless for this question. If you need to use a reactive variable akin to a shiny `input$` you'll have to create one using a `reactiveValues()` function call. If you are just assigning a value to a variable, a reactive variable is not needed. If you are trying to reset the value of a previously created to NULL you'll have to create a reactive variable and set it to NULL. The following is how to set a non-reactive variable to a value or to NULL using a button.

```
actionButton("do","Putlabelhere")
observeEvent(input$do,{
    rhm_clic <- value #or NULL
    return(rhm_clic) 
#the return is not needed but a good idea for beginners
}
```

Comment: I did not know that I could not change the inputs that way. I also used your methods but they did not work. At the end I opted to create a button action from JavaScript and use the Shiny.onInputChange JavaScript function. The following code, in the ui, solved my problem



`HTML('<button id="mydiv" type="button" 
       class="btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input"> Mexico</button>'),
 tags$script('
    document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = function() {
      var number = Math.random();
      Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", number);
    };
  ')`

Comment: The code solved my problem is\\


    ```HTML('<button id="mydiv" type="button" 
    class="btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input"> 
    Change The Value</button>'), 
    tags$script(' document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = function() {
    var number = Math.random(); Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", number); }; ')```