# Update a value to an input$value without input$ logic

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the value of an `input$value` that my shinyapp generates. To do this

I have tried with:

```
observeEvent(input$click,
             input$vis$start[1]<- "2019-01-09T03:00:00.000Z"
            )
```

But the response that I have is:

```
Warning: Error in $<-.reactivevalues: Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object
  [No stack trace available]
```

All the code:

```
library(timevis)
library(shiny)


data <- data.frame(
  start=c("2019-01-10","2019-01-11"),
  end =  c("2019-01-11","2019-01-12")
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  br(),
  timevisOutput("vis"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("click","da")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$uno <- renderTimevis(

    timevis(data,options=list(editable=TRUE,stack=FALSE))
  )


  observeEvent(input$click,

               input$vis_data$start[1]<- "2019-01-09T03:00:00.000Z"

               )
  output$table <- renderTable(
    input$vis_data

  )

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please remove the part of code which is not relevant with the problem.

Comment: This just produces a blank page with the button `da` on it for me. I'm guessing there is supposed to be more.. Are you able to focus on just this `vis_data` part and make some dummy data so the eg runs out of the box, please? I don't get the error as I don't have the data. Edit: I don't use shiny much, but I have used the function `reactive` before to take a data object and update it based on an input, might be of use. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/reactive.html

Comment: You need timevis library to reproduce the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the input value in shiny from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267911/change-the-input-value-in-shiny-from-server)

Answer (score 0):

While @anotherfred is correct that this issue has been discussed, it was not fully answered there.

Consider this minimal app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  print(input)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Console:

```
...
...
$readonly
[1] TRUE

$ns
function (x) 
x
<bytecode: 0x000000000c417de0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You will see in the console that `input` has a `read-only` attribute. Of course attributes could theoretically be overwritten.

See the discussion here:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/167#issuecomment-108412945

That would result in: `attr(input, "readonly") <- FALSE`. I remember i tried this some time ago and it worked. Not sure it still works, but it is actually not that important. Because, it is certainly not best practise and most of the time there will be a better way to achieve the desired output.

In your case, I would use a reactiveValue instead and make the data within `renderTimevis()` reactive. If you add a reproducible example, we can discuss it in detail. I see the same output like Jonny Phelps mentioned in the comment (with timevis library loaded,...)

Comment: does this result in any form of exposure or vulnerability?

Comment: I would recommend asking this in the rstudio community or on github to the authors. Would be more of a rough guess from me.